# Simple JQuery selector does not find ID within a string

Tags: jquery, string

```
var chk = "<div id='test'>Trying</div>";

    alert($("#test",chk).html());
```

Well this JQuery by String is not working its so simple but it doesn't work =/ What is it wrong in it ? thanks in advance!

Comment: @Felix Kling - Actually you can pass a string as a context. See: http://jsfiddle.net/GpdYz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var chk = "<div><span id='test'>Trying</span></div>";
alert($("#test",chk).html());
```

The **first parameter** "#test" is your **selector** (what you really want to get).

And the **second parameter** chk is your **context** (within your query / search is performed).

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I wanted, but its weird, why its necessary another wrapper, and I've already tested with <html><body><div id='test'>Trying</div></body></html> and it didn't work out, Thank you very much!

Comment: @user668138: Probably `<html><body>` gets filtered out by jQuery (or the DOM) because you cannot create these elements.

Comment: Since I'm here I have another question related, I get a string that comes like this -> &quot; <- and when I get the .html() it auto-converts the -> &quot; <- to  -> " <-, how do I do to get the content without that auto-conversion? I want &quot not "  Thanks!

Comment: I can't use text() because I get a big number of divs so I have to get the div tags, so to get the div tags I have to use .html() and when I do it, it auto-converts them =/

Comment: Hmmm. You should be able to use a selector to drill through the `<div>`'s and then finally use `.text` once you reach the div you need. Maybe it would help if you posted a "real-world" example of the type of div structure you need to traverse.

Answer (score 3):

SunnyRed hit the nail on the head.

The trouble is that when you say:

```
$("#test",chk)
```

You are searching for all DOM elements within (and not including) the `chk` tag. Unfortunately because that tag contains `#test`, your search does not find anything. Consider the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

If you wrap your string with a root-level `<div>` and then try the search, you will get what you are after:

```
var chk = "<div><div id='test'>Trying</div></div>";
alert($("#test", chk).html());
```

For a live example, see: http://jsfiddle.net/GpdYz/

Answer (score 1):

```
alert($(chk).html()); // Trying
```

Comment: Yea but if I had more divs (and there are much more) it would bring all the result, I need to get a specific id div content.

Comment: Or `alert($(chk).text());` depending on if html or text is required.

Comment: @user668138: Once you append `chk` to your document (e.g., `$('body').append(chk)`, you can target the element simply by its ID.)

Comment: @wanovak - But why should he have to? For example, if he retrieved the data via an AJAX call, he may just want to retrieve the data from the string. There may be no reason to append it to the DOM.

Comment: @Justin Ethier: He doesn't have to. As SunnyRed said, there needs to be context. Context can be attained in a number of ways. Appending it to the DOM is just one way.